# How to share gradients and variables in Adam optimizer when using bucketing in Tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, tensorflow, deep-learning

All,

I used bucketing-like technology for seq2seq task:

```
# For different length in encoder and decoder
model_map = {}
for i in encoder_shape:
    for j in decoder_shape:
        with variable_scope.variable_scope(variable_scope.get_variable_scope(),
                                 reuse=True if tt > 0 else None):
            model = Seq2SeqModel()
            model.build(encoder[:i], decoder[:j])
            model_map[i*100+j] = model
```

And get shared model's parameters:

```
for t in tf.all_variables():
    print t.name, t.get_shape() 

Print: 
embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/EmbeddingWrapper/embedding:0 (50000, 256)
embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Matrix:0 (1056, 1600)
embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Bias:0 (1600,)
```

Model's optimizer is like below:

```
#every model have an optimizer
params = tf.trainable_variables()
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3)
gradients = tf.gradients(self.loss, params)
self.optimizer = opt.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, params))
```

But I find that the optimizers don't share variable:

```
embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/EmbeddingWrapper/embedding/Adam:0 (50000, 256)
embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/EmbeddingWrapper/embedding/Adam_1:0 (50000, 256)
embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Matrix/Adam:0 (1056, 1600)
embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Matrix/Adam_1:0 (1056, 1600)
embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Bias/Adam:0 (1600,)
embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Bias/Adam_1:0 (1600,)
embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/EmbeddingWrapper/embedding/Adam_2:0 (50000, 256)
embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/EmbeddingWrapper/embedding/Adam_3:0 (50000, 256)
embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Matrix/Adam_2:0 (1056, 1600)
embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Matrix/Adam_3:0 (1056, 1600)
embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Bias/Adam_2:0 (1600,)
embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Bias/Adam_3:0 (1600,)
```

With the growth of the number of buckets, the GPU memory will grow too. And meanwhile I get a larger model in tf.train.Saver.save().

So is it possible to share gradient in bucketing in tensorflow?

Comment: @Lukasz Kaiser Please give some help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe sharing a single optimizer instance across all your models will do the thing you want.